# Array_push 2d array

Tags: php, html, sql, database, array-push

I am having this array_push problem when i run the php. The echo printed 3 times but my array didnt get pushed 3 times however only once.
**My Input**: Read from Php Database ID and Occupied. eg. ID = A1 Occupied = 1 or 0(either one)
**What i want for my Output** :A 2d array
eg: echo $seats[0][1] = 1
$seats = array(array("A", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

The errors they show me is "Undefined offset".
Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID,Occupied FROM booking";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $seatrow = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $rowA = array("A");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<br> id: " . $row["ID"] . " Seated? " . $row["Occupied"] . "<br>";
            if (strpos($row["ID"], 'A') !== False) {
                array_push($rowA,$row["Occupied"]);
                array_push($seatrow,$rowA);
                echo $seatrow[0][2];

            }
        }
            }
```

Comment: That means `strpos($row["ID"], 'A') === False`

Comment: Does the second echo: `echo $seatrow[0][2];` get displayed?

Comment: nope only [0][1] and [0][0]

Comment: @AbraCadaver its not that line, i tried

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense at all, You're modifying $rowA in a loop & pushing it again into $seatrow which means it will just keep growing for no apparent reason, Please provide the input & expected output data so we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ahmad I am actually reading from the PhP database. I need the ID and  occupided's value to form a 2d array Eg: ID = A1,Occupided = 1 or 0
My if condition is to make this A array
Next will be a B Array:
array(array("A", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
array(array("B", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Result = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strpos($row["ID"], 'A') !== false) {
        $Result['A'][] = $row["Occupied"];
    }elseif(strpos($row["ID"], 'B') !== false) {
        $Result['B'][] = $row["Occupied"];      
    }   
}
var_dump($Result);
```

This should return what you want, while using 'A' OR 'B' as the key of the array for easier access. 
So if you want to check for 'A' you'll only `foreach ($Result['A'] as $Occupied)`

Ofcourse you can do something like `foreach ($Result as $Group => $Occupations)` then you can `foreach ($Occupations as $Occupied)` within it to get the status for each item in the list.

Comment: You can check for $Seats in 'A' Group like this ``$SeatsAvailableInGroupA = in_array('0', $Results['A'])`` this should return either TRUE when you have something that's no occupied or FALSE when all the values are 1.